# A little problem with pst-plot

Tags: errors, pstricks, pst-plot

I am getting error with this code:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{ucs}
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc} 
\usepackage[ukrainian]{babel}
\usepackage{fontenc}
\usepackage{inputenc}
\usepackage{calc}
\usepackage{pstcol}
\usepackage{pstricks,pst-plot}
\usepackage{pst-text}
\usepackage{pst-char}
\psset{xunit=0.7cm,yunit=5cm}
\begin{document}

\begin{pspicture}(-7.5,-0.4)(7.5,1.2)
\psaxes[Ox=0,Oy=0,Dx=1,Dy=0.2,linecolor=black]{->}(0,0)(-7,-0.3)(7,1.1)
\end{pspicture}

\end{document}
```

Code error:

```
! Undefined control sequence.
<recently read> \c@lor@to@ps
l.17 \end
{pspicture}
```

Help me please. Whats wrong?
P.S. Sorry for my bad english

Comment: Did you compile it with pdflatex? You must compile it with `latex->dvips->ps2pdf` sequence

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are trying to generate `postscript` picture directly from `{pdf|lua}latex`, it cannot be done this way. Use `\usepackage{auto-pst-pdf}` and run one the following commands (in depends on the TeX distribution you are using):

```
lualatex --shell-escape your-file.tex
lualatex --enable-write18 your-file.tex
```

The next option is to use a sequence of tools `latex->dvips->ps2pdf->pdfcrop` plus loading PDF file using the `\includegraphics` command from the `graphicx` package. I enclose your example rewritten for the first method and a preview of your sample picture.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\pagestyle{empty}
\usepackage{auto-pst-pdf}
\usepackage{ucs}
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc} 
\usepackage[ukrainian]{babel}
\usepackage{fontenc}
\usepackage{inputenc}
\usepackage{calc}
\usepackage{pstcol}
\usepackage{pstricks,pst-plot}
\usepackage{pst-text}
\usepackage{pst-char}
\psset{xunit=0.7cm,yunit=5cm}
\begin{document}
\begin{pspicture}(-7.5,-0.4)(7.5,1.2)
\psaxes[Ox=0,Oy=0,Dx=1,Dy=0.2,linecolor=black]{->}(0,0)(-7,-0.3)(7,1.1)
\end{pspicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: mwe]

Comment: With `xelatex` you do not need any additional package or an editional conversion!

Comment: @Herbert Thank you for letting me know. I have deleted `xe` in the post.